# How do I create in libGdx my own font drawn in .png?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a font in .png. How to use it in LibGdx?I searched everywhere, but everywhere they say to use some kind of .ttf file

Comment: .png is an image, if you want to use it as a font who will have to do a lot a stuff for select letter in the picture and put in your actor. 

ttf file describe font so if you use a ttf file you just have to point use your .ttf as an asset for your skin. 

You can find png to ttf converter online. I have not try it but this is the simpliest way

Answer (score 0):

In **libGDX** the `BitmapFont` class can be used to use a `.png` file together with `.fnt` file as a font.
The `.png` file contains the graphics for each letter and the `.fnt` file contains information about where in the `.png` file each letter is located.

Normally one starts with a actual font (like a `.ttf` file) and then use a tool such as the [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) font tool that can generate both the `.png` file and the `.fnt` file, but you can also create the `.fnt` file manually, although it might be a tedious task.

You can have a look at the [default.png](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-tools/assets/default.png) and [default.fnt](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-tools/assets/default.fnt) to see the format of the `.fnt`.

Again, it might be tedious using a graphics program to find all the coordinates for every character and map them to the correct ascii value but remember you only have to map the characters in the `.png` file that you actually plan to use.

Comment: There’s a free desktop app called Shoebox that can convert a bitmap image of letters into a .fnt and associated packed image.